# Error when inserting large data set from SAP HANA to SQL server with ODBC

Tags: sql-server, odbc, hana

I am trying to insert a large data set of about 11 million records from SAP HANA database to a SQL database using an ODBC driver. However, during the insert of the dataset I see that some data is inserted into the SQL database. However, after a couple of minutes I got the following error:

> Could not execute 'INSERT INTO "SDA"."TAT" SELECT * FROM tat_table' in 6:23.297 minutes.
>
> SAP DBTech JDBC: [403]: internal error: Error executing query [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2714 for query " INSERT INTO "TAT" ( "ReceiptTime", "Mnemonic", "Name", "Urgency", "Minutes", "Category", "Amount") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

Smaller dataset about the 100.000 records it is possible to insert in the SQL database.

I also have tried to commit the data after 50.000 records every time but this was also not the solution does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to transfer data ?

Comment: In our company we dont have SSIS